# The AND gate 7408 electrical engineering

Tags: integrated-circuit

I put an AND gate on my breadboard with all connections correct. I also mounted two  switches (SPST switches) at the inputs. My problems is when my two switches are on (the button pressed) the LED is off, when I turn the switches off (the button up) the LED is on.

I want to fix this, I want the led to turn on when the switch is on (the button is pressed) and vise versa.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Draw a circuit unless you think EE has some kind of mind-reading facility.

Comment: You haven't said whether your switches tie the AND inputs to ground or to Vcc; what kind of pull-up or pull-down resistors you used; and whether the LED is connected between the AND output and ground or Vcc. Please include a schematic to make these kinds of details clear.

Comment: @Andyaka Context with previous questions gives Kreskin-like powers, but it would be 100% better if the question was self-contained.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany As far as I can tell from the user history, this is the first question of the OP in EE SE so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @alexan_e There was a very similar 7408 question recently. A different member of the same class or a different ID for the same person? The chip is pretty much obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

If you can tie your switches to the +5V rail instead of ground, and put pull-down resistors from each of the inputs to ground you could make this work without extra gates.  Assuming what you want is for the output to go high when BOTH switches are on at the same time.

Comment: That will "work", however the resistor has to be very low value (like a couple hundred ohms) for standard TTL to see a solid '0', and also it is bad karma to tie TTL inputs directly to +5V as any musty old TTL manual should warn (and that's what the switches would do). For example, see http://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-363.pdf page 2 (ca. 1984). So, it's not good design advice, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, good points, Spehro, I agree.  I wouldn't use this technique in a production design, but on a breadboard just to see the function of an AND gate it would let him see it work.  500 ohm pull-downs would be sufficient according to my old TTL databook.  Another option instead of tying directly to VCC, he could use a single inverter, input tied to ground to provide a logic high to tie the switch to.

Comment: it worked by just putting pull down resistors. Thank you for sharing your knowledge with us.

Answer (score 0):

Add inverters in front of the gate inputs. For example, 1/6 of a 7404 on each. The switch is best used to pull a TTL input LOW so you have an inherently inverted function.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ZQ7Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that if you'd used a 7400 quad NAND gate you could have used one gate as an inverter on the output, giving you the AND function and the remaining two gates on the inputs.

Non inverting gates are not as flexible, which is probably why they're not as popular.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXW9gg.png)</sup>

Note also that the equivalent to an AND gate with inverters on the inputs is a NOR gate.